# What does “ for” imply here?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure

When we leave to a place basically we say, "I am leaving to America tonight", or "I am leaving for America tonight" (not sure if this sentence is used)

What I personally think is that the preposition ‘for’ is used when we represent for the subject. Like, say, I’m playing for America, or I’m leaving for my company.

Am I wrong? Either way, if we leaving to a place for a trip or holiday is ‘for’ the correct preposition to be used?

Comment: Yes, one leaves for a place, not to a place. Use "to" with the verb "go", thus "I'm leaving for America tonight" ~ "I'm going to America tonight".

Comment: You _are_ wrong, I'm afraid. We say "I'm going/travelling _to_  America", but "I'm leaving _for_ America". I suppose _for_ implies _with the intention of arriving there_.

Comment: In "I'm going to America" "to" has its core use of indicating the goal in physical movement ("to America"). "For" typically indicates the beneficiary or recipient of something, but it also has a number of grammaticised uses, one of which is to indicate destination, where it is selected by verbs like "leave" and "head" ("leave/head for America")

Answer (score 1):

'For' is certainly not interchangeable with 'to' in most contexts. They have different uses. We use 'for' to indicate *purpose* or *aim*. It is used in the context of journeys only when the destination is already a stated purpose.

When we have a planned trip, it is common to refer to the entire trip including the journey and the stay by the place name. For example, if we had a trip to London planned and we had told others about it already we might say "London is in 2 weeks".

So, if we were to say:

- I'm leaving for London in the morning

It is as if we were saying:

- I'm leaving for *my trip to* London in the morning.

Your other example of "I'm leaving for my company" doesn't sound right. We do say "*I'm leaving for work*", meaning we are about to make our journey *to go to* work. But 'for my company' sounds like you are doing something that your company wants you to do.